# Consistently Getting Error: $injector:nomod Module Unavailable When I Load My App

Tags: angularjs

I think it has something to do with the way my files are ordered but I can't figure out which ones are causing the problem.

```js
angular.module('app')
.controller('langCtrl', function($scope, languageService){
  $scope.submit = function(model) {
    console.log(model);
    languageService.analyzeDocument(model)
  }
});
```

```html
<html lang="en" ng-app="app" class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>WIT</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="images/computer.ico"/>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
</head>
<body ng-controller="langCtrl">
  <div class="header">
    RecommendHER
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <script src="languageService.js"></script>
  <script src="langCtrl.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I put the index.html file and my controller in the snippet. I also have a service on the save level as app.js and the controller file. Here is the code:

```
angular.module('app')
.service('languageService', function($resource) {
  var apiUrl = 'http://xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com';

 var languageResource = $resource(apiUrl + {}, {
 analyzeDocument: {
   method: 'POST',
   url: apiUrl + '/analyze_document?file=:text'
 },
 analyzeWord: {
  method: 'POST',
  url: apiUrl + '/recommend?word=":word"'
}
 });

  return {
    analyzeDocument: function(data) {
       return languageResource.analyzeDocument({data:text}).$promise;
     },
      analyzeWord: function(data) {
       return languageResource.analyzeWord({data:word}).$promise;
     }
   };
 });
```

Here is my app.js file:

```
angular.module('app', [

]);
```

Comment: check the answer, you need to change the order in index.html

Comment: Use the link in the error to go to angular error docs to tell you what problem is

Answer (score 0):

You need to add empty dependencies to your module,

```
angular.module('app',[])
```

**EDIT**

Change the order in index.html to make your module load first,

```
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="languageService.js"></script>
<script src="langCtrl.js"></script>
```

Comment: I've tried both of those things and now I see an unknown error for my provider service

Comment: you need to include ngResource as a dependency to your module also refer it in html

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined the 'app' module with two parameters yet:

```
angular.module('app', []).run(function() {});
```

The one parameter version expects app to already exist in order for things to be included as part of the module.

Also, ensure that the app.js file is loaded first.

Comment: I see, you need to put the app.js first in order then.

Comment: I've tried that and now I am seeing an unknown provider error for my language service